# I have confusion while translating propostions to logical expressions

Tags: discrete-mathematics, propositional-calculus

I have following propositions:
`p:Grizzly bears have been seen in the area.`
`q:Hiking is safe on the trail.`
`r:Berries are ripe along the trail.`

I need to convert following compound statement to logical expressions by using logical connectives.

`If berries are ripe along the trail,hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area`

What I think is true is:

`~p <-> (r^q)`
Note:I have considered `comma` in above statement as `and`.
But answer given at the end of book is:

`r -> ( q <-> ~p )`

Comment: What you came up with doesn´t seem likely, as it basically says that not having seen grizzly bears tells us something about ripeness of berries along the trail, which seems absurd. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma is not to be read as an and, it is the "then" of the first *if*.
So.

> If berries are ripe along the trail, then the following holds: hiking is safe if and only if bears have not been seen in the area

Thus

> If $r$, then ($q$ if and only if $\neg p$).

Answer (score 0):

Its simple first read .....Berries are ripe along the trail. it means "r" and in the start there is If so it means implies after that........hiking is safe if and only if grizzly bears have not been seen in the area if and only if ka matlb bidirectional Q<-->not p :)